# How do I conditionally hide an element inside a repeater using only server-side?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

My situation is the following: I have a repeater that lists rows from a table. The last element in each row is an asp:Button. The problem is that under certain conditions this button should not be displayed.

How do I do it so it doesn't show?

Obs. I'm not allowed to use client side operations.

Comment: You have provide no where near enough information. What have you tried to date? What are these mysterous conditions. Start by googling the ItemDataBound event for ASP.repeaters.

Answer (score 0):

One property of the items that you are binding to the repeater should be a boolean indicating whether or not the button should be shown.

Bind that property to the `Visible` property of the button.